# How to capture a variable's current value for a block

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Is there a way to save the current value of a varible for later usage in a block?

For example, for this Playground code:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class testClass {
    var i = 0
    func test() {
        let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) * 5)
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.test(self.i)
        })
        i = 3
    }

    func test(i: Int)
    {
        print("i: \(i)")
    }
}

let a = testClass()
a.test()
```

Is there a way to save the current value of `i` for `dispatch_after` in a way that I get the output `i: 0` instead of `i: 3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind an arbitrary expression to a named value in a *capture list*,
the expression is evaluated when the closure is created. In your case
you would bind `self.i`:

```
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [i = self.i] in
    self.test(i)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're referencing `i` through a captured `self`, you will get whatever the value is at dispatch time.  If you want to capture the value as it is at the beginning of the function, you'll need to get a local copy before changing it.

```
    let x = self.i
    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.test(x)
    })
```