# Can I force evaluation of an @autoclosure parameter?

Tags: swift, parameters, initialization, closures

Consider code like this:

```
func log(_ msg: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Any?) {
    print(msg)
}

class Foo {
    let bar = 3
    let lazy: String

    init() {
        log("bar is \(self.bar)")
        self.lazy = "always late"
    }
}
```

This does not compile:

> Error: 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

Fair enough: even though there clearly is no problem here, the compiler can't be expected to figure out that (arbitrary) closures don't use `self` in ways that are undefined (yet).

Of course, I can work around this by doing:

```
let bar = self.bar
log("bar is \(bar)")
```

But this seems clumsy.

Is there a way to tell the Swift compiler to evaluate the `@autoclosure`-parameter upfront, that is in essence to ignore `@autoclosure`?

PS: I copied this signature from XCGLogger. I'm not sure why `@autoclosure` is needed there.

Comment: "I'm not sure why @autoclosure is needed" The way _you_ have defined `log`, the `@autoclosure` serves no purpose. — I think your workaround is fine. It's hard to see what the problem is. If you want the goodness of autoclosure, what you are doing is what you have to do.

Comment: Actually, the way you have defined `log`, it doesn't even log properly. :) See my correction, in my answer below.

Comment: @matt Quite right! The inevitable oversights in MWE-construction...

Comment: The reason for using autoclosure in a logger function is that the argument is evaluated lazily, and not evaluated at all if logging is disabled. Compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828261/logtrace-equivalent-in-swift-language-iphone, or https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=4 where that technique is demonstrated for an "assert" function. – The `@escaping` attribute seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: Wouldn't `@escaping` also be required for laziness?

Comment: @BallpointBen: No. It would only be required if the passed closure is called *after* the log function returns (which is not the case).

Comment: @MartinR Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a trampoline between you and `log`, like this:

```
func log(_ msg: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Any?) {
    if let msg = msg() {
        print(msg)
    }
}

func mylog(_ msg: Any?) {
    log(msg)
}

class Foo {
    let bar = 3
    let lazy: String

    init() {
        mylog("bar is \(self.bar)")
        self.lazy = "always late"
    }
}
```

Comment: Inline version: `{ log($0) }("bar is \(self.bar)")`

Comment: @robmayoff Brilliant. I feel a bit dizzy just looking at it...! :)

Comment: Hm. In a way, that's a different flavor of the same clumsiness -- but a valid approach, still.

Comment: @robmayoff Cute, but not very practical. ;) Wouldn't want that to have many times in the code.

Comment: @Raphael The point is that you've no choice. You _can't_ magically pre-close the autoclosure, so you _have_ to work around this _somehow_ — put the mention of `self` after initialization has finished, or do the workaround you're already doing, or use a trampoline to evade the compiler's eagle eye.

Comment: One can use a capture list to make a closure capture "bar" instead of "self", so this compiles and works as expected: `let clo = { [bar = self.bar] in "bar is \(bar)" } ; log(clo())`, even before self is fully initialized. However, I was not able to do the same with a single statement, e.g. `log({ [bar = self.bar] in "bar is \(bar)" }())` does not compile. – It isn't nice anyway, just wanted to mention it.

Comment: @MartinR I've never seen an assignment in a capture list.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html: *"... or a variable initialized with some value (such as delegate = self.delegate!)"*. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37301478/1187415, to bind the value of a variable at the time when the closure is created.

Comment: @MartinR Great use case.